# Navigation bar with everything centered except one element floated right

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to center 4 elements beside each other and have one that floats right with a flex solution.

What the best result would be that if I where to resize my browser that the floated would stay put and the 4 elements would take up all the rest till no space is left.

I've been trying to find a non-flex solution with no hope of doing the dynamic thing.

Either I have overlooked an oblivious answers to this or it's not possible.

I can complete adjust my code and even add JS/JQuery solutions - I don't mind really.

Appreciate all help :)

Comment: "to center 4 elements beside each other" What ?

Comment: to have buttons or links like home, inbox etc

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of options, one using float and the second using absolute positioning.

In the first case, the centering takes into account the width of the floated element.

In the second case, the centering is with respect to the width of the parent element.

The centering is achieved by using `text-align: center` on a set of `inline-block` child elements.

```css
.nav {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  position: relative;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
.rightfloat {
  float: right;
}
.rightpos {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Ex 1:</p>
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="rightfloat">Right Most</li>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
  <li>Fourth</li>
</ul>

<p>Ex 2:</p>
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="rightpos">Right Most</li>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
  <li>Fourth</li>
</ul>
```